# C++ Set enum class value according to two chars

Tags: c++, linux, c++20

I have a field in a message header which denotes the message type. The field is two chars, like "AR". I'd like to represent this using an enum class so I can enforce all types are handled on a `switch` statement.

Inside the `enum class` we will see the enum's value is defined by the two char values. However, I'm struggling because it must be a `constexpr`.

This doesn't compile but I'm after something like this:

```
enum class AnEnum : uint16_t
{
    value_one = atoi(std::string("AR").c_str()),
    value_two = atoi(std::string("PF").c_str())
};
```

In the above example one message header contains the chars AR and another message type contains PF.

Comment: i think you actually want `const char* value_one = "AF";`

Comment: Why not just right your own `constexpr` atoi?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Unfortunately not because I want to use enum class so I can enforce all types being handed in any switch statement.

Comment: enum is just a int, you can define a static string array and use enum as index.

Comment: ok, but then I dont understand what is `atoi("AR")`.  `"AR"` is not a string representation of an integer and `atoi` would return `0` for both calls

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I believe OP wants the integer encoding of "AR": `std::uint16_t{'A'*256+'R'}`. This would sync with them using `std::uint16_t` as the enum's base type.

Comment: @bitmask yes I can imagine what they actually want, but what they wrote in code makes no sense ;). @ OP please describe what you want. Broken code is not good in explaining what it is supposed to do, because it is just broken

Comment: @bitmask yes, correct

Comment: @Cwift I don't follow that suggestion? Can you elaborate as an answer?

Comment: what values do you want? what would you write if you would hardcode the values? `value_one = 42; value_two = 123;` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number bitmask has already stated the answer.

Comment: but then.. would you be fine with this https://godbolt.org/z/xzjazeqM7 ? What I dont understand (and that might be just due to me being slow in understanding stuff ;) is that the what you want just works and only the code that does not actually do what you want causes errors.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I didn't totally follow that but maybe if I elaborate on my usage: I receive a message. In the header, lets say the first two bytes, are two chars denoting the message type. I would like to cast those two chars to an enum (the one being asked here) class which is `uint16_t` under the hood. Then I can use a switch statement on this enum. Does this make more sense?

Comment: well, once its clarified what you really want its just a matter of writing it down and I do not see the problem anymore. Nevermind, I wrote it down in an answer

Comment: @bitmask Technically you got it first so if you put an answer i'll accept.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is how I implementd:

```cpp
enum class E {
    AR = 0,
    PF = 1
};
static constexpr const char* ENUM_STRS[] = { "AR", "PF" };

void foo() {
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    E e = E::PF;
    switch (e) {
    case E::AR:
        cout << ENUM_STRS[static_cast<int>(e)] << endl;
        break;
    case E::PF:
        cout << ENUM_STRS[static_cast<int>(e)] << endl;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I went with bitmask's answer but gave you an vote for this.

Answer (score 1):

`atoi` converts integer string representations to integers. `"AR"` and `"PR"` arent integers, hence `atoi` is not what you want.

Thanks to bitmask this is what you do want:

```
enum class AnEnum : std::uint16_t
{
    value_one = std::uint16_t{'A'*256+'R'},
    value_two = std::uint16_t{'P'*256+'F'}
};
```

For a string recieved in a message you do not need to convert it at compile time because the string is only known at runtime. Only to avoid duplication it is handy to have it at compile time so that the same conversion can be used for the enum values.

```
constexpr std::uint16_t convert(const char x[2]) {
    return x[0]*256+x[1];
}

enum class AnEnum : std::uint16_t
{
    value_one = convert("AR"),
    value_two = convert("PF")
};
```

[Complete Example](https://godbolt.org/z/jP74bfqWW)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I went with bitmask's solution but gave you an upvote for the alternative.

Comment: @mezamorphic not sure what you mean, this is bitmasks solution

Comment: I meant he mentioned it first :)

Comment: erm yes. My intention surely was not too steal the rep. The thing is that you cannot accept a comment as answer. Its just a comment. But you should accept an answer when you consider the question as answered